# Firebase not inserting data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a Firebase database and I'm trying to store values in it from an Android application. The database path is correct (see "Log" row) but I can't see the data in the db, it's still showing "db-name-default-rtbd:null". Why?

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
Log.d("database", "path: $database");
database.setValue("xyz")
```

Log prints this: path: https://db-name-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: yes, both addOnSuccessListener and addOnFailureListener, no one of them is invoked

Comment: If none of those methods fires, most likely there is no internet connection on the user's device.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database is a JSON-like structured database where you have a key and a value. Now you are trying to set some string value to the root of the database which is not allowed.

So, you need to get a reference not on the root of your database, but on some path and then set a value to that reference. A sample snippet:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("cat").child("name").setValue("Kitty");
```

Comment: As far as I know you _can_ call `setValue()` on any `DatabaseReference` including the one to the root. It may be unusual to store a single value in the database, but it is possible so I don't think that explains the problem OP is having.

Comment: Since we set a value to a `DatabaseReference` of a child with the name `name`, it will be a key-value pair of `name = Kitty` which is nested in a `cat` object.

Comment: @IvanTaranov I've tried your solution but it doesn't work; with or without child nodes, database remains null

Answer (score 0):

In your firebase console navigate to project settings and try to add SHA-1 value . After that download the "google.json" file and add it to your android project. Clean and Build then try to run your project it will work.